# How to filter a dataview rows by monthcalendar?

Tags: vb.net

Respected Sir,
 I am trying to filter dataview by monthcalendar bythe below script, but i am not getting rows fitered. whats the error i am doing in this script ?

```
 If Me.myDataSet.myTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim myDataView As New DataView
                myDataView.Table = Me.myDataSet.myTable
                Dim myDate As String = String.Format("[vstime] = '{0:M/dd/yyyy}' ", MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date)
                myDataView.RowFilter = String.Format(myDate)
      End If
```

yours faithfully
Murulimadhav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved it by this example
[How to use BindingSource.Filter for a Date in visual basic 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860206/how-to-use-bindingsource-filter-for-a-date-in-visual-basic-2012)
or is there any simpler solution than this ?

```
Public myFilterDate As DateTime
Public Sub myDayFilter(ByVal myFilterDate)
    If Me.myDataSet.myTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        myFilterDate = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date
        Dim dateFrom As DateTime = myFilterDate.Date
        Dim dateTo As DateTime = dateFrom.AddDays(1).Subtract(New TimeSpan(1))

        Dim filterBuilder As New StringBuilder()
        Dim filterFormat As String = "vstime {0} #{1:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}#"

        With filterBuilder
            .AppendFormat(filterFormat, ">=", dateFrom)
            .Append(" AND ")
            .AppendFormat(filterFormat, "<=", dateTo)
        End With
        Me.myBindingSource1.Filter = filterBuilder.ToString()
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateChanged
        myDayFilter(myFilterDate)
    End Sub
```

thanking you
Your faithfully
Murulimadhav