# BindingSource Filter Datagridview, SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

Using SQL Server Management Tools I created a view with the following

```
SELECT ID, 
       Groupname, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, TimeSub, 103) AS Date,
       RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), TimeSub, 22), 11) AS Time, 
       TK, 
       CProblem, 
       Fix,
       Username, 
       Closed_Date, 
       Reason
FROM dbo.log
```

I needed to seperate TimeSub into 2 fields 1 for Date and 1 for Time in AM/PM.

Using VB2012

```
Dim sqlSelectCommand As New SqlCommand(("Select * from log order by ID DESC"), CS)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlSelectCommand)

    adapter.Fill(DTable)
    BS.DataSource = DTable
    DG1.DataSource = BS

BS.Filter = ("Date >= '" & Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "'")
'BS.Filter = ("Groupname = 'SW'")
```

What should happen is the datadridview should only show todays date based on the Date Column, it doesn't work, it shows all dates.

If I used the Groupname SW it sorts Groupname showing all records with SW in them. To me it's like the convert in the SQL view isn't working properly.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: is this msql or sql-server ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860206/how-to-use-bindingsource-filter-for-a-date-in-visual-basic-2012)

Comment: What is your database MySQL or SQL-Server and also please share the table full definition with column names